# Google Driving directions gadget not auto expanding

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, driving-directions

I am trying to embed the Google Driving directions gadget into an xhtml website. However when the location is set the gadget does not auto expand and holds the size defined in the original specification. The information is all pulled in, scrolling down with the arrow keys will reveal it, but no scroll bar is provided. I got the js code from [Here](http://aht7hjsu8d8du5dgd917aohtlkinfcj7.open.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&brand=light). If anyone knows how I could force a scroll bar, or knows why it wouldn't auto expand, I would really appreciate an answer.
Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem...anyone able to shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with this last night and finally understand the problem.  You've probably figured it out and moved on, but in case others are having the same issue...

As far as I can tell, **the Google Directions Gadget doesn't auto-expand unless you're running it server-side.**  I just ran it with my local XAMPP server, and it works!

I hope this is helpful to others.

Dan

Comment: Thanks, on uploading it works fine :) Pain in the arse that it wont work offline though.